# Can Vim NerdTree be used as a buffer explorer

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I have been using vim NerdTree for sometime now. One thought came to my mind and i am not sure if it is possible so seeking the help of experts.

Can Nerdtree show the list of open buffers say something like *:NerdtreeBuffers*

I know there is *BufferExplorer* but i dont like it for the simple fact that i have to pre-define if i want the buffer in a tab/split/vsplit

Nerdtree is awesome ... i just need one command and then from the list i can open it however i want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, NERDTree doesn't have any buffer list/exploration properties. I like [Buffergator](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3619) ([GitHub](https://github.com/jeetsukumaran/vim-buffergator)) for quick buffer listing & selection. By default, it operates similarly to NERDTree, opening a left vertical split and allowing you to navigate to a buffer and hit enter to jump to it. It also supports opening buffers in vertical/horizontal splits, and other basic functionality. [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) is also handy. It does fuzzy find on files, but can also limit itself to open buffers.